# C# Searchbox in a WPF Application with a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Hi I have searched on the site and didn’t quite find an answer to what my question is.  I read this one: http://davidowens.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/wpf-search-text-box/ that was suggested from another question someone had about wpf searchbox.
 I have a C# WPF application where I am using Access DB. On my data entry screen I have a search box and a data grid that displays all the records in the db.  The search I currently have works but not the way I thought it would. I want the user to be able to start typing in the search box and the list of records shown in the data grid will start to filter based on what they type.  The code I wrote I thought would do that but in order for them to do a search they have to for example type: people*  then hit enter and it will display the results.  I want to know is there a way to modify my code to not require the asterisk and to filter as they type or should it be written differently?
My data entry xaml page textbox name below:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtSearch" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="14" Margin="10, 0, 10, 0" Text="{Binding Path=SearchString,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

On my datahelper.cs below:

```
    private void Search(string inputSearchString)
    {
        inputSearchString = inputSearchString.ToLower();

        LastSearchTerm = inputSearchString;

        FilteredCaseCollection.Clear();

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputSearchString.Trim()))
        {
            foreach (CaseViewModel caseVM in CaseCollection)
            {
                FilteredCaseCollection.Add(caseVM);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            inputSearchString = inputSearchString.Replace(" =", "=").Replace("= ", "=").Replace(" = ", "=");

            string[] termsArray = inputSearchString.Split(' ');

            int count = 0;

            foreach (CaseViewModel caseVM in CaseCollection)
            {
                count++;
                Type t = caseVM.GetType();
                foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in t.GetProperties())
                {
                    if (propertyInfo.CanRead)
                    {
                        object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(caseVM, null);

                        if (value == null)
                        {
                            value = String.Empty;
                        }

                        string name = propertyInfo.Name.ToLower();

                        foreach (string term in termsArray)
                        {
                            if (term.ToLower().Equals(value.ToString().ToLower()))
                            {
                                if (!FilteredCaseCollection.Contains(caseVM))
                                {
                                    FilteredCaseCollection.Add(caseVM);
                                }
                            }
                            else if (term.ToLower().Contains("*") && MatchWildcardString(term.ToLower(), value.ToString().ToLower()))
                            {
                                if (!FilteredCaseCollection.Contains(caseVM))
                                {
                                    FilteredCaseCollection.Add(caseVM);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public bool MatchWildcardString(string pattern, string input)
    {
        if (String.Compare(pattern, input) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pattern.Trim(new Char[1] { '*' })))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (pattern.Length == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (pattern[0] == '?')
        {
            return MatchWildcardString(pattern.Substring(1), input.Substring(1));
        }
        else if (pattern[pattern.Length - 1] == '?')
        {
            return MatchWildcardString(pattern.Substring(0, pattern.Length - 1), input.Substring(0, input.Length - 1));
        }
        else if (pattern[0] == '*')
        {
            if (MatchWildcardString(pattern.Substring(1), input))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return MatchWildcardString(pattern, input.Substring(1));
            }
        }
        else if (pattern[pattern.Length - 1] == '*')
        {
            if (MatchWildcardString(pattern.Substring(0, pattern.Length - 1), input))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return MatchWildcardString(pattern, input.Substring(0, input.Length - 1));
            }
        }
        else if (pattern[0] == input[0])
        {
            return MatchWildcardString(pattern.Substring(1), input.Substring(1));
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: how do you call this `Search` method? do you call it in the `TextBox`'s `TextChanged` event handler?

Comment: /// <summary>
        /// Gets/sets the current search string
        /// </summary>
    public string SearchString
        {
            get
            {
                return this._searchString;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this._searchString != value)
                {
                    this._searchString = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SearchString");
                    Search(SearchString);
                }
            }
        }

Comment: so `Search` method is called on every keystroke? can you confirm that?

Comment: Yes it is called on every keystroke. For Example if I put in T it will call it then I type * it will call it again.

Comment: If your search is triggered on every key stroke what seems to be the problem then? I assume your `DataGrid` is bound to some underlying collection which you have access to. And you can append the asterisk to your inputSearchString in the Search method itself, can't it?

Comment: What @CyberSensei wants, i guess, is after typing `t`, all properties with a value starting with `t` are filtered out; now the code only filtered the properties that have the exact value as he types, unless * is explicitly appended.

Comment: @Jerrington I want to not use the asterisk. I would like to be able to type T alone and return all records with a T in it. Currently it will not return any results until I put in the asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

This requires an exact match

```
if (term.ToLower().Equals(value.ToString().ToLower()))
```

Change it to "StartsWidth" can do the trick.

```
if (value.ToString().ToLower().StartsWith(term.ToLower())
```

If you type "t", then a property with value of "thursday" will match.

Or try if `Contains` is what you want.

```
if (value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())
```

Comment: I changed it to StartsWith but now it doesn't filter at all. When in debug the string SearchString contains the value of T. I even put * after the T and it would not filter out just those records.

Comment: I tried Contains but how I wrote the code it still required that I put the *, which is what I am trying to get away from is using the * all together. I'm sure there is a easier way to do a search of records from a db in a datagrid w/o it.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a simple form of what you are doing. I am placing the XAML and the ViewModel here. I basically created a list of clients then copied the list to a filtered list. I then bound my DataGrid to the filtered list.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox x:Name="txtSearch" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="14" Margin="10, 0, 10, 0" Height="28" Width="74"
             Text="{Binding Path=SearchString, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredClients, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClient}" />
</Grid>

    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        allClients = new List<Client>();
        filteredClients = new List<Client>();
        GetAll();
    }


    public const string SearchStringPropertyName = "SearchString";
    private string searchString = string.Empty;
    public string SearchString
    {
        get
        {
            return searchString;
        }

        set
        {
            if (searchString == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            searchString = value;
            if (searchString == string.Empty)
            {
                filteredClients = allClients;
            }
            else
            {
                FilterAll();
            }
            RaisePropertyChanged(FilteredClientsPropertyName);
            RaisePropertyChanged(SearchStringPropertyName);
        }
    }

    public const string AllClientsPropertyName = "AllClients";
    private List<Client> allClients;
    public List<Client> AllClients
    {
        get
        {
            return allClients;
        }

        set
        {
            if (allClients == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging(AllClientsPropertyName);
            allClients = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(AllClientsPropertyName);
        }
    }

    public const string FilteredClientsPropertyName = "FilteredClients";
    private List<Client> filteredClients;
    public List<Client> FilteredClients
    {
        get
        {
            return filteredClients;
        }

        set
        {
            if (filteredClients == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging(FilteredClientsPropertyName);
            filteredClients = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(FilteredClientsPropertyName);
        }
    }

    public const string SelectedClientPropertyName = "SelectedClient";
    private Client selectedClient;
    public Client SelectedClient
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedClient;
        }

        set
        {
            if (selectedClient == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging(SelectedClientPropertyName);
            selectedClient = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(SelectedClientPropertyName);
        }
    }

    private void GetAll()
    {
        AddClient("sally", "may", 10000);
        AddClient("bert", "benning", 10000);
        AddClient("ernie", "manning", 10000);
        AddClient("lisa", "ann", 10000);
        AddClient("michael", "douglas", 10000);
        AddClient("charlie", "sheen", 10000);

        filteredClients = allClients;
    }

    private void AddClient(String firstname, String lastname, Double salary)
    {
        Client clientadd = new Client();
        clientadd.FirstName = firstname;
        clientadd.LastName = lastname;
        clientadd.Salary = salary;

        allClients.Add(clientadd);
    }

    private void FilterAll()
    {
        filteredClients = (from c in allClients where c.FullName.Contains(searchString) orderby c.FullName select c).ToList();
    }

}

public class Client
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public Double Salary { get; set; }
    public String FullName { get { return LastName + ", " + FirstName; } }

    public List<Client> Clients { get; set; }

}
```

I needed no asterisk and my search was very simple. I hope this helps.

Comment: it definitely is more straight forward than my approach. I will give it a shot.